# continuity and oscillation of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I would be very grateful if somebody could verify my proof

Exercise: Prove that a function $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ in $A$ if and only if the following condition is satisfied: for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$, such that $\Omega_{] c-\delta, c+\delta[\cap A} f<\varepsilon$

My approach:  We know that $\Omega_{A} f=\sup _{x, y \in A}|f(x)-f(y)|$.

First let $f$ be continuous at $c$. Choose $\delta$ such that $|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then if $x,y \in ] c-\delta, c+\delta[$.

$$\Downarrow$$

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(c)|+|f(y)-f(c)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$$

$$\Downarrow$$
$$\sup _{x, y \in A}|f(x)-f(y)|< \varepsilon$$

For converse direction just choose $y=c$. Then $$\sup _{x, y \in A}|f(x)-f(c)|< \varepsilon $$
$$\Downarrow$$

$$|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$$

Comment: First direction fine, second direction you don't just choose $y = c$. Instead   you also choose an appropriate $\delta$ first. I.e. you appeal to $\Omega_{] c-\delta, c+\delta[\cap A} f<\varepsilon$ for said $\delta$ and then for all  $x \in A: \left| x - c\right| < \delta \implies \left|f(x) - f(c)\right| < \varepsilon$ is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your second arrow does not follow. The implication is not true for all $x,y \in A$. It is true when $|x - c| \leq \delta$ and $|y - c| \leq \delta$.
2. The statement $\sup_{x,y \in A} |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ is a bit vague since y is not arbitrary. You chose it to be c.

You're in the right direction. Remember the definition of continuity at a point.